# Check if all object keys exist as values in an array of objects

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have these 2 entities

```js
const obj1 = {key1: "", key2: "", key3: ""};
const array2 = [
  {
    name: "key1",
  }]
```

How can I check if `array2` has an object with the name of each field in `obj1`?

Basically I'd like to end with array 2 becoming this:

```js
const array2 = [
  {
    name: "key1",
  },
{
    name: "key2",
  },
{
    name: "key3",
  }]
```

Comment: You want to *"check if `array2` has an object"*, or you want to *transform* `array2`…?

Comment: Check if it has an object with a name property of the value equal to all the keys in obj1, if not push one.

Comment: Check this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kfwsogjq/

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
const obj1 = {
    key1: "",
    key2: "",
    key3: ""
};

const array2 = [{
    name: "key1",
}, {
    name: "key2",
}];

const obj1Keys = Object.keys(obj1);
const array2KeyNames = array2.reduce((array2KeyNames, obj) => {
    array2KeyNames.push(obj.name);
    return array2KeyNames;
}, []);

for (let i = 0; i < obj1Keys.length; i++) {
    if (!array2KeyNames.includes(obj1Keys[i])) {
        console.log(obj1Keys[i], ' is not in the array2');
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I ended up writing the following which is a bit simpler I reckon,

Comment: for (var x in obj1) {
  if (!array2.some(c => c.name === x)) {
    array2.push({
      name: x,
    });
  }
}